# Unix Epoch time to Date returns strange results

Tags: swift, timestamp, unix-timestamp, epoch

```
let postDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: feeds[indexPath.row].creationDate)
print("UNIX TIME: \(feeds[indexPath.row].creationDate)")
print("DATE: \(postDate)")
```

The first print command is printing the

> UNIX TIME: 1511530358000.0,
>   UNIX TIME: 1511418618000.0,
>   UNIX TIME: 1511002194000.0

The second print command is printing

> DATE: 49868-06-28 07:53:20 +0000,
>   DATE: 49864-12-13 01:00:00 +0000,
>   DATE: 49851-10-03 07:40:00

Why am i getting wrong date results? When i test the same unix timestamp in this [website](https://www.epochconverter.com/) it gives me correct answer. Im using xcode 9.1 9B55

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `creationDate` is in milliseconds, not seconds. You need to divide by 1000.

```
let postDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: feeds[indexPath.row].creationDate / 1000)
```

Comment: OMG im so silly. Coding since 10am till 10pm made my brain stop functioning.  Thanks rmaddy.